# Powershell parameter sets - two optional sets with mandatory/optional parameters

Tags: powershell, parameters

I feel I'm nearly there with this one but can't see the wood right now.

I have a function which needs two parameter sets, they are both optional, but each set has mandatory parameters when used and I need to be able to run both sets together if required:

```
Function Submit-CSRwithSAN {
   [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='MyDefault')]
        Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType ‘Leaf’})]
        [string]$CSRinPath,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$CertAuth,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="MyDefault",Mandatory=$false)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="CSRequest",Mandatory=$true)]
        [switch]$SubmitToCSR,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="CSRequest",Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$RequestTemplate,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="MyDefault",Mandatory=$false)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="AddSANs",Mandatory=$true)]
        [switch]$AddSAN,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="AddSANs",Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$SanDNS1,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="AddSANs",Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$SanDNS2,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="AddSANs",Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$SanIP,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="AddSANs",Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$CSRoutPath
    )
```

So, desired output is (I think)

```
Submit-CSRwithSAN -CSRinPath <string> -CertAuth <string> [-SubmitToCSR] [-AddSAN]  
Submit-CSRwithSAN -CSRinPath <string> -CertAuth <string> -SubmitToCSR -RequestTemplate <string> [-AddSAN -SanDNS1 <string> [-SanDNS2 <string>] [-SanIP <string>] [-CSRoutPath <string>]]
Submit-CSRwithSAN -CSRinPath <string> -CertAuth <string> -AddSAN -SanDNS1 <string> [-SanDNS2 <string>] [-SanIP <string>] [-CSRoutPath <string>] [-SubmitToCSR -RequestTemplate <string>]
```

At present this function only runs with one parameter set or the other, not both - can someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Parameter sets are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Step 1: define all your parameters.  Step 2: Add as many `[Parameter()]` attributes for each set you want that parameter in.  Step 3: fill in the attribute with the correct names.  As a note: making switches mandatory (in your second/third set) is an extremely odd decision.

Comment: Thanks for the direction - it's the first time I've done anything complex with parameters. Is there is a better way to handle this requirement? Would learning to code dynamic parameters be a bettter solution?

Comment: Dynamic parameters are probably the only way to fulfil your requirements. Parameter sets don't support what you're asking.